# Sequelize insert query getting foreign key id by name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have table `audits` and table `actions`. Audit references a foreign key `id` from `actions`.

`audits`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LOCK |
| 2 | UNLOCK |

How do I write sequelize query inserting an audit record providing name of an action for it to give me the id to store in the audits table? Something like this but in sequelize

```
insert into audits (account, audit_action_id)
select 'abc123', (select id from actions where name = 'LOCK')
```

Expected audits (e.g. account being locked and then unlocked)

| id | account | audit_action_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 | 1 |
| 2 | abc123 | 2 |

Audit model has `auditActionId` but in order to provide it I have to query it by name string

```
audit.save({
  account: 'abc123',
  auditActionId: '???',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize can't combine INSERT and SELECT and moreover from different tables. You need to execute a query to get an action by a name and then use `id` value from it.

```js
const foundAction = await Action.findOne({
  where: {
    name
  }
})
if (!foundAction) {
  throw new Error('Action not found')
}
const newAudit = await Audit.create({
  account: 'abc123',
  auditActionId: foundAction.id
})
```

OR
if you have `hasMany` association from `Action` to `Audit` like this:

```js
Action.hasMany(Audit, { foreignKey: 'auditActionId' });
```

then you can use the special method generated by Sequelize according to registered associations:

```js
const const newAudit = await foundAction.createAudit({
  account: 'abc123',
})
```